# Testing urfave/cli based applications with go

Tags: go, testing, command-line-interface

I'm writing a small CLI application in Golang using urfave/cli framework and I'd like to write tests for it, but I can't find any useful information on how to test CLI applications, specifically written with the urfave/cli library. I have a lot of flags in the application and some of them are mutually exclusive and I'd like a proper test to stay on top of them - does anyone have an idea how to do it the right way?

EDIT:
Consider the following minimal example of application with several flags and restrictions around them. How would you test these flags usage (requirements, exclusivity, etc.) and how they influence the functions when they're set or not?

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/urfave/cli"
)

func doSomething(flag1 string, flag2 string, flag3 bool, flag4 bool) error {
    err := errors.New("something")
    return err
}

func main() {
    app := cli.NewApp()
    app.Name = "greet"
    app.Usage = "fight the loneliness!"

    var flag1, flag2 string
    var flag3, flag4 bool

    app.Flags = []cli.Flag{
        cli.StringFlag{
            Name:        "flag1",
            Value:       "",
            Usage:       "flag1",
            Destination: &flag1,
        },
        cli.StringFlag{
            Name:        "flag2",
            Value:       "",
            Usage:       "flag2",
            Destination: &flag2,
        },
        cli.BoolFlag{
            Name:        "flag3",
            Usage:       "flag3",
            Destination: &flag3,
        },
        cli.BoolFlag{
            Name:        "flag4",
            Usage:       "flag4",
            Destination: &flag4,
        },
    }

    app.Action = func(c *cli.Context) error {

        if flag1 != "" && c.NumFlags() > 1 {
            fmt.Println("--flag1 flag cannot be used with any other flags")
            cli.ShowAppHelp(c)
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        if flag1 == "" && flag2 == "" || c.NumFlags() < 1 {
            fmt.Println("--flag2 is required")
            cli.ShowAppHelp(c)
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        if flag3 && flag4 {
            fmt.Println("--flag3 and --flag4 flags are mutually exclusive")
            cli.ShowAppHelp(c)
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        err := doSomething(flag1, flag2, flag3, flag4)
        return err
    }

}
```

Comment: The general answer would be "the same way you test anything else". If there is some specific aspect you're having trouble with, can you clarify your question and if possible provide a sample of the code you need to test?

Comment: @Adrian If that's so, then why isn't there any real examples for testing CLI applications, but rather only some bits of code (functions) inside them? I've specifically said I'm having troubles with coming up with tests for flags.

Comment: Outside of a handful of GUI experiments, basically **all** Go programs are CLI programs, so generally speaking, every example for testing in Go is an example for testing CLI applications. You have some code that does some stuff. It needs to be designed in a way that it is testable, then tested. Without seeing your code, there's no real way to offer more advice than that.

Comment: @Adrian I'm sorry, but that level of generalisation, while technically correct, isn't very helpful. Docker isn't a 'GUI experiment' but we wouldn't call it a 'CLI program' (perhaps with exception for the CLI Docker command). Neither is kube-apiserver, and we still wouldn't call it that. I've also clarified the flags case, which you've ignored.

Comment: Generalizations are all that can really be offered *without seeing the code you're trying to test*. And those programs you listed are definitely CLI programs; they are executed from the command line, taking command line flags and parameters.

Comment: As usual, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example will increase the chance that somebody will be able to help you. What have you tried ?

Comment: @marco.m question updated with example code.

Comment: Thanks for the code; on the other hand it doesn't compile, the flags are undeclared. I made the effort to copy the code in my editor, please make the effort to give us working code.

Comment: @marco.m The code was simply a pseudocode to display the case I'd like to test. Here you go, a code that compiles.

Comment: The code compiles and exits silently and immediately. My attempts finish here.

Comment: @marco.m I'm sorry, I don't understand your point, you wanted me to provide a code sample that complies, so I did?

Answer (score 0):

As Adrian correctly wrote

> the same way you test anything else

Given a slightly modified example of the sample code of the project

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "log"
  "os"

  "github.com/urfave/cli"
)

func Friend(c *cli.Context) error {
  fmt.Println("Hello friend!")
  return nil
}

func main() {
  app := cli.NewApp()
  app.Name = "greet"
  app.Usage = "fight the loneliness!"
  app.Action = Friend

  err := app.Run(os.Args)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
}
```

Since this code actually prints something instead of returning a value you can evaluate, you could use a [testable example](https://blog.golang.org/examples)

```
func ExampleFriend(){
   // Yeah, technically, we can save the error check with the code above
   // but this illustrates how you can make sure the output
   // is not what the testable example expects.
   if err := Friend(nil){
     fmt.Printf("Friend: %s",err)
   }

  // Output:
  // Hello friend!
}
```

Note that `Action` expects an [`ActionFunc`](https://godoc.org/github.com/urfave/cli#ActionFunc). Where you define that `ActionFunc` is pretty much your thing. It could even come from a different package. So it is your design on how good your application will be testable.

**Edit** The signature of the value Action expects will change in the future, at least [according to the docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/urfave/cli#App). I already find it questionable to use `interface{}` to be able to pass nil to Action, and then check and type assert for ActionFunc, where a no-op ActionFunc would actually serve the same purpose, but removing an error return value *really* makes me scratch my head. I strongly recommend to have a look at [alecthomas/kingpin](https://github.com/alecthomas/kingpin) for smaller to medium size applications or [spf13/cobra](https://github.com/spf13/cobra), which is suitable even for the most complex of cli applications.

Comment: I've updated the question with slightly modified code, showing the flags I am concerned about. How would you write tests for those?

Comment: @SpankMe Again: Do NOT write them as a "closure", as shown. Make them a named function, and reference that function in "App.Action". Then, you can test it all you like.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand, could you please provide an example on how to do that?

Comment: @SpankMe I did above. See `App.Action = Friend`

Comment: I still don't understand, your example does nothing with flags, and it is specifically flags testing (the CLI nature of the application) that I am having problems wrapping my head around.

Comment: @SpankMe You pass your flags to a function. This function is externalized. So you can set the values as you see fit. Remember: you do not unittest `urfave/cli`, you unit test *your code*. Which you can do with the sample above.

Comment: I've externalised the action function, but I still struggle to test anything - how do I set cli flags for the testing function or how do I check these flags values if things like cli.Context are being set when the actual application code executes, not the test code? Would you be able to amend your example to reflect even a single flag?

Comment: @SpankMe Again - you do not test flags. You test functions. A function which now has a name, after you externalized it. PLEASE read the links I gave you - the testable example example should show you that I call `Friend` with nil. With an externalized function, you can follow https://golang.org/pkg/testing/. You do not call your program with flags. You call functions. Functions. no program.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, how to extract `*cli.Context` from var `app` if one like to call Friend(c *cli.Context) from ExampleFriend()?